# Android: How to know which Calendar type is being used by a device

Tags: android, time, calendar, android-calendar

How can I get the Calendar type being used on a specific device like Gregorian, Chinese, etc...?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a proper way to do this, mostly because Android only provides the Gregorian calendar (as far as I know)

Don't know if it could help, but the class `GregorianCalendar` is a subClass of `Calendar` which takes care of all the gregorian standards, have a look here:
[GregorianCalendar](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html)

Also, for an approximate Calendar identification based on a timezone, you could  call `TimeZone.getDefault()` and handle the output in a switch case.

Answer (score 0):

**You could only ask for the preferred calendar of given system locale**. [CLDR-data](http://www.unicode.org/repos/cldr/trunk/common/supplemental/supplementalData.xml) have entries for such informations (inside the tag calendarPreferenceData). For example: Iran prefers persian calendar but the gregorian one is also possible.

Another story is the **available calendar support**. If you plan to use the standard class `java.util.Calendar` then you will be strongly disappointed because there are only subclasses for gregorian, thai-buddhist and japanese.